# Hot swapping in Spring Boot

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I've been doing a P.O.C with Spring Boot.

So far it's been going really good and promising, but there's one major drawback: I'm using an embedded server (i.e., packaging the web app in a `.jar`), so when developing I have to rebuild the jar and restart the server every time I change the CSS, HTML or JS files. There's not hot-swap. This really slows down the UI development.

I can think of several quick fixes, such as loading static resources off a different domain and serving it from a local `nginx`, and some more variations like this, but isn't there a built-in option of some sort when working with IntelliJ/Eclipse?

Comment: If you don’t mind switching from spring boot, you can try mason http://github.com/metamug/mason It’s built to be fast and redeploy on change.

Answer (score 28):

There are several options. Running in an IDE (especially with debugging on) is a good way to do development (all modern IDEs allow reloading of static resources and usually also hotswapping of Java class changes). Spring Boot devtools is a cheap way to get quite a big boost (just add it to your classpath). It works by restarting your application in a hot JVM when changes are detected. It also switches off things like thymeleaf caches while it is running, so you don't have to remember to do that yourself. You can use it with an external css/js compiler process if you are writing that code with higher level tools.

[Spring Loaded](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded) is no longer recommended, but probably still in use. More sophisticated agent-based tools work much better if you need hot swapping with zero delay (e.g. JRebel).

See the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-hot-swapping) for some up to date content

Comment: Thanks dave i'll take a look into spring-loaded and the maven option for reloading static files, one question: i'm running idea12 and i can't find a way for repackaging a static resource when running an embedded tomcat in an annotation driven configuration, are you sure it should work?

Comment: I'm not a regular IDEA user but I don't know of any problems. I worked on a project last year where everyone used it and never had any issues. It must be possible. Maybe you have to add src/main/resources explicitly to your classpath?

Comment: I'm also having a problem getting this to work within IntelliJ.  I followed the spring boot reference and made sure my cache setting was set to false for Thymeleaf, but whenever I change a template located under src/main/resources, I have to restart the application running the embedded container

Comment: I didn't realize I could get STS to hot-reload `.class` files just by launching in debug mode. Thanks!

Comment: @RoyKachouh Dave is correct. See my answer for instructions (it's really simple!)

Answer (score 15):

> but isn't there a built-in option of some sort when working with IntelliJ/Eclipse?

What helped me in IntelliJ 15.0, windows 10, was the following sequence:

**STEP 1:** Added the following dependency in pom (This is mentioned everywhere but this alone dint solve it), as mentioned by @jonashackt

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**STEP 2:** Then from File->Settings-> Build-Execution-Deployment -> Compiler (make sure main compiler option is selected and not any of its sub-options)

enable **Make Project Automatically**. Click ok and close the dialog
Note : In latest version it will be **Build project automatically**

**STEP 3:** Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (on windows) you will see a search dialog with title "Enter Action or option name", type registry. Double click the first option that says "Registry..." it will open another window. Look for the following option:

```
compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running
```

and enable it, click close

**STEP 4:** Restart IDE

Elaborated from this [source](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-application-live-reload-hot-swap-with)

Comment: This just restarts the SpringBoot on save file or?

Comment: no it doesn't, it lets you reflect the changes on saving.

Comment: Yes but when I save it restarts SpringBoot from start. I just wanted to class that changed to be loaded.

Comment: Thymeleaf templates & static resources can be reloaded without building, if you source them from the filesystem rather than the classpath:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/72928208/768795

Comment: not having  compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running with build:
Build #IU-231.9161.38, built on June 20, 2023

Answer (score 7):

You can get hot swapping:

- for java code: using [spring-loaded](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded)
- for Thymeleaf templates: disabling the cache

Check this post to see more details: http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/05/21/hot-swapping-in-spring-boot-with-eclipse-sts/

Comment: Thymeleaf templates & static resources can also be reloaded without building, if you source them from the filesystem rather than the classpath:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/72928208/768795

Answer (score 6):

I do not know how far this kind of support goes, but in case you use Eclipse IDE (or anyone reading this): **starting up your Spring-Boot application via m2e in debug-mode** (press the "Debug"-dropdown button and pick your maven run configuration item).

It works for me like a charm.

My maven run configuration item is configured as follows:

- goal is set to "spring-boot:run"
- base directory is the project directory

I am **not using** any further libraries (not even spring-boot-devtools).

That's it.

Comment: Hot code replace (HCR) only works when the class signature does not change; Make sure that 'Project > Build Automatically' is checked. SEE: https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_hot_code_replace%3F

Answer (score 5):

You can also use JRebel - it will reload all changes (better hotswap) including spring beans. It is easily integratred with both Intellij and Eclipse.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are using gradle; use the following config in your build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'application'

applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=localhost:7000,server=y,suspend=n"]

mainClassName = "package.ApplicationRunner"
```

Run the application from the IDE or command line using the command `gradle build run`

Now the IDE can connect to the remote JVM (on port 7000) where the spring boot application runs. It also supports hot deployment of static files.

or even you can run the main class from intelliJ if the dependencies are properly managed in the IDE. The main class is the class that contains the main method which will call `SpringApplication.run("classpath:/applicationContext.xml", args);`

Answer (score 5):

In Intellij, I can get this behavior. When the program is running in debug mode, select `Run > Reload Changed Classes`

Note: After Intellij completes the action, it might say `Loaded classes are up to date. Nothing to reload`. This is misleading, because it actually DID reload your classpath resources.

My environment/setup includes:
Intellij 13
Embedded Tomcat
Run/Debug configuration of type 'Application' (which just uses a main class)
Serving static html, css and js (no jsp)

Answer (score 5):

try using this spring-boot-devtools tag in pom.xml

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

http://mytechnologythought.blogspot.com/2017/07/how-to-run-server-of-spring-boot-auto.html

Comment: Why `optional=true`?

Comment: @nabster Optional dependencies are used when it's not possible (for whatever reason) to split a project into sub-modules. The idea is that some of the dependencies are only used for certain features in the project and will not be needed if that feature isn't used. Ideally, such a feature would be split into a sub-module that depends on the core functionality project.... Read more:
https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

Answer (score 3):

From 1.3.0. (now in Milestone 2) on, you can use the spring-boot-devtools for that as a lightweigt approach - see the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-devtools) or [this blogpost](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/17/devtools-in-spring-boot-1-3).
Simply upgrade to >= 1.3.0. and add the following to your pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Than start your SpringBootApplication with Run As... and you´re fine.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/) (template engine), [jRebel for personal developer](https://my.jrebel.com/).
Thymeleaf template files are just HTML resources. So, they`re changed immediately after you edit template files.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using maven, the spring-boot-maven-plugin in your pom.xml needs to be like this to get the hot swap:

```
  <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

and if you're using thymeleaf, add this to your application properties:

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

But remember something: Don't use this in your production environment..

Answer (score 0):

**How to perform Hot Swap in Springboot Application**

1. When using gradle include following in the dependency:
   `compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-devtools', version: '2.0.1.RELEASE'` & `providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')`
2. In ***application.properties*** add the property `spring.devtools.restart.additional-paths=.`
3. Build Gradle and then run application as bootRun

The application is ready to perform hot swap on modification of classes