# Hot Deployment with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, maven, jetty, spring-boot

Usually I was able to set the `scanIntervalSeconds` when I used the Jetty Maven Plugin for Java Web Projects. Now I'm building a Spring Boot project and wonder if it's possible to achieve Hot Deployment. I couldn't find anything in the official Spring docs.

Any suggestions?

**pom.xml:**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: What's the `refreshInterval` for? Refreshing what? Is it a jetty feature or a Maven plugin feature?

Comment: It is called ``scanIntervalSeconds``  and seems to be a Jetty Maven Plguin feature => http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_JSP#Jetty_Maven_Plugin

Comment: It checks for code changes and enables automatic redeployment.

Comment: Looks like the same question as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399586/spring-boot-developer-machine). Does that help?

Comment: @DaveSyer Yep, thank you. Probably I've used the wrong keywords for my search on here.