# spring boot hotswap with Intellij IDE

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-boot, hotswap

I have a spring boot application running fine with Intellij IDE. i.e i started the Application class that has the main method which delegates to SpringApplication.run. Everything works great except hotswap. When I change the source, I am forced to re-start the application. Even If I start the application in debug mode, I dont see hotswap working. I could see that Intellij's Debug settings have hotswap enabled.

My observation shows that when I run the springboot application, classpath used is my

```
/projects/MyProject/classes/production/....
```

Files under `classes/production` are not getting updated when I change the code. Intellij IDE compiles the files but does not update classes/production directory. How do I get hotswap working with IntelliJ IDE for spring-boot?

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399586/hot-swapping-in-spring-boot/43114954#43114954

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Found out the root cause. This has nothing to do with Spring-boot. On changing my groovy source files, files were not auto-compiled.

To recompile changed files and swap them:

- `Ctrl+Shift+F9` on Windows
- `Cmd+Shift+F9` on Mac

Comment: How to diable restart project every time when one file is changed

Comment: You can use a trigger file. See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-restart-triggerfile

Comment: For the skeptical, [the keymap](https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf) lists this shortcut as, "Compile selected file, package or module".

Comment: Among all these not working answers, this is the only useful!

Answer (score 120):

A solution that uses devTools works :

#### 1 - Adding devtools to your project

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

#### 2 - Enabling automatic build

Open *the Settings --> Build-Execution-Deployment --> Compiler and enable :*

```
Build Project Automatically.
```

#### 3 - Update the value of compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running

press `ctrl+shift+A` and search for the `registry`. In the registry, enable :

```
compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running
```

---

References :

- https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-application-live-reload-hot-swap-with

Comment: Does this not only restart SpringBoot, as when you do it manually? Takes the same amount of time during restart?

Comment: `compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running` will restart every time when any file is changed. It took too long time

Comment: I tried this and it did not work for me.  Is it perhaps b/c i have multiple maven projects in my Intellij Project?  If so, I'm not even sure how to solve that b/c the "Build Project Automatically." setting is seemingly a global Intellij setting

Comment: The last step (updating `compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running`) is not needed at least with IntelliJ Ultimate edition.

Comment: The app only restarts when I close the file, and all spring boot is restarted, it's not a true hot reload... am I missing something? I'm using idea Ultimate

Comment: The last step is to restart IntelliJ to make it work.

Comment: In 2019.2 the "Build project automatically" setting have a note "(only works when not running/debugging)".   It appears that automatically hotswapping must be enabled in the debug launch configuration.

Comment: Don't forget to disable auto-save

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen where can I enable the hotswapping. I checked the launch configuration, but I did not find it. Is it a launch command parameter or something?

Comment: @Jaanus open a new question

Comment: In 2021.2 instead of step 3 enable *Settings --> Advanced Settings --> Allow auto-make to start even if developed application is currently running*

Comment: Just a helpful note for macOS users. if cmd+shift+a doesn't work, you can try shift+shift which should open the dialog box and there you can search for Registry.

Comment: Thanks @maechler this solved my issue.

Comment: As of version 2022.2 see [Reload modified classes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2022.2/altering-the-program-s-execution-flow.html#reload_classes). And for the IntelliJ [Ultimate Edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/buy/#commercial) only _[Spring Boot run configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2022.2/run-debug-configuration-spring-boot.html#modify-options) → Modify option → On 'Update' action_

Answer (score 32):

Step 1: [Add developer tools denpendency](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html)

**Maven**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

or ..

**Gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
}
```

Step 2: Go to **File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler**

enable **Build project automatically** & **Apply** & **OK**

[image]

Step 3: Press shortcut key **Ctrl+Shift+A** & Search **Registry** keyword & Press Enter

[image]

Enable **compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running** & Click **Close** Button

[image]

Step 4: **Disable cache** on your favorite web browser

[image]

Step 5: Done!!!

## Watch Solution On YouTube

[image: Solution]

Comment: If your Action Window close immediately from second time after you typed `Registry` in Mac version, you could hit `Shift` button twice to pop the Action Window again.

Comment: Thank you @shellhub

Comment: Additionally after 2021.2 version, complier.automake.allow.when.app.running  option was moved to Advanced settings. Preferences -> Advanced Settings -> Compiler -> Allow Automake ..... so on...

Comment: Couldn't find this in 2021.3.3 CE

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-274903/In-IntelliJ-2021.2-compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running-disappear.-Unable-to-enable-live-reload-under-Spring-boot

Answer (score 17):

In my case even after adding the Spring Boot dev tools and checking the build project automatically, it was not working. What was missing was this:

1. Go to the project run configuration.
2. Set on'Update' action and 'On frame deactivation' both to 'Update classes and resources'. 
   And it worked like a charm.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I cannot find 'Update' and 'On frame deactivation' in my Intellij. Can you help?

Comment: This is exactly why I wrote a comment: I don't see any on 'Update' Action and on Frame Deactivation options when clicking on Run -> Edit Configurations. (I am on Intellij 2018.1.6)

Comment: Could you send a screenshot or a link to it when you click on Edit Configurations? That would make it easier to see what is going on.

Comment: @RichArt I was having same issue. Unfortunately, the run config been spoken about is for intellij spring-boot support - only available in ultimate edition.

Comment: @BinaryMonkL: I am working on the Ultimate edition. Do I miss something else?

Comment: @RichArt you need to configure it as a spring app and select the spring boot run config from left tab

Comment: I would go with @BinaryMonkL 's suggestion. You will need to make sure that your project is configured as a Spring App. Did you create this project using Spring Initializr? That is the best way to make sure Intellij brings in tools to support Spring Boot.

Comment: Did the trick for me. Is there a way to set this configuration as the default for all projects?

Answer (score 9):

Use [spring-loaded](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-reload-springloaded-gradle-and-intellij). It works fine with bean reloading. It's free alternative to JRebel.

Another way is to use [DCEVM](http://ssw.jku.at/dcevm/) or [hotswapagent](http://www.hotswapagent.org/)

Comment: It's perfect except the Mybatis mapper.xml, after changing myapper.xml's sql code, the reload not work

Answer (score 5):

I noticed the same problem as well. I am on the Intellij 13.1.1. and for it to hotswap the changed class. I have to run the app in debug mode, then after changing the class, select "Run->Reload Changed Classes" manually.

I also have the debugger set to hotswap as indicated in http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/reloading-classes.html but doesn't seem to work.

Anyway, at least the manual "Run->Reload Changed Classes" menu works.

Answer (score 5):

@Sameer Khanal's answer worked but since so much time has passed, I offer some clarification

1. Install the spring boot devtools dependencies (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-devtools)
2. Modify your run option
   [image: Edit running configuration]
3. Update the options for `On 'Update' action` and `On frame deactivation` like so:
   [image]
4. Click on OK and you are done

Hope that helps

Comment: Works only in ultimate edition.

Answer (score 2):

For multiple changes, use "Compile And Reload File"(Add "spring-boot-devtools" first). Double click "Shift" to show the diagram in Mac.

Or try [spring-loaded](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded) which I haven't tried yet. But seems it could work.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the deployment artifact exploded, in the deployment tab, this did the trick for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can use either of the following methods to auto reload Thymeleaf templates:

1. Spring Boot Dev Tools
2. Change Thymeleaf Templates Path
3. Gulp Watch

I recommend [Gulp watch](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/watch) as it is easier to setup and works great:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'), 
watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    return watch('src/main/resources/**/*.*', () => {
            gulp.src('src/main/resources/**')
                //replace with build/resources/main/ for netBeans
                .pipe(gulp.dest('out/production/resources/')); 
    });
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

Now enter the following command in your terminal to start gulp watch:

```sh
$ gulp 
//OR
$ gulp watch
```

I wrote a blog post on [auto reloading Thymeleaf templates without restart in IntelliJ IDE](https://attacomsian.com/blog/spring-boot-auto-reload-thymeleaf-templates).