# HotSwap IntelliJ like Eclipse

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

In eclipse oxygen my Spring Boot app restarts automatically as soon as I change any Java file. In IntelliJ I did not find a function like this. Can I achieve the same in IntelliJ too? I often read about HotSwap but I cannot get it work with Spring Boot. I also read about spring devtools. But do I really need this if I just want to reload my classes after changes?

Comment: See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/v2/issue/IDEA-141638

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spring boot hotswap with Intellij IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155244/spring-boot-hotswap-with-intellij-ide)