# hot swapping not working for Spring boot with Intellij and spring-boot-starter-web

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot, spring-boot-starter, spring-boot-devtools

My spring boot microservice uses spring-boot-starter-web and I'm trying to enable hot swapping in intellij.  I tried adding the this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

and then in Intellij I:

checked "Build project automatically" in compiler settings
AND
checked the compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running box
AND restarted Intellij

I ran my microservice, then changed a controller file, and nothing happened...any ideas?  Is it b/c I'm using spring-boot-starter-web and consequently embedded Tomcat?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Along with the steps that you've followed already, did you mind doing this as well? This seems to be answered already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155244/spring-boot-hotswap-with-intellij-ide).

Give it a try and let me know if it works for your case too!

Update the value of `compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running`

Press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`A` and search for the registry. In the registry, enable:  `compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running`

Comment: I did try those things already....thx tho.  I'm wondering if it's b/c in my Intellij project I have like 30 diff maven projects....maybe if i had just the one it would work ?  :/

Comment: You could then give it a try with a new workspace only having just one project!