# Spring Boot application failed to hot swap changes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I`m working on a Spring Boot project and I tried to switch our IDE from STS to Intellij CE. Everything is working fine except when debugging. Whenever I change a Java class, the Spring tries to restart the whole application and fail with the following message:

```
web - 2018-09-27 08:39:18,494 [restartedMain] WARN  o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.xyz.service.IUserService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
web - 2018-09-27 08:39:18,496 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
web - 2018-09-27 08:39:18,498 [restartedMain] INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Stopping service [Tomcat]
web - 2018-09-27 08:39:18,524 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.a.l.AutoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
web - 2018-09-27 08:39:18,871 [restartedMain] ERROR o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter - 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field userService in com.xyz.controller.UserController required a bean of type 'com.xyz.service.IUserService' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.xyz.service.IUserService' in your configuration.
```

Here is some context about the environment:

1. The spring-boot-devtools 1.5.9 dependency is added to our pom.xml
2. The option "Preferences->Build, Execution, Deployment->Compiler->Build project automatically" is checked
3. I've tried debug with the option "cmd+shift+a->Registry->compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running" both checked and unchecked
4. The IDE version is

   [IDE version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIsd7.png)
5. The spring-boot-starter-parent version is 1.5.9.RELEASE
6. The following structure describes the class hierarchy:

```
com.xyz
|-service
|  |-IUserService
|  |-impl
|     |-UserService
|-controller
   |-UserController
```

7. UserService.java is annotated with @org.springframework.stereotype.Service
8. UserController has the following field:

   ```
   @Autowired
   private IUserService userService
   ```

Also, I've tried all the answers from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155244/spring-boot-hotswap-with-intellij-ide) but didn't manage to solve the problem. Has anyone faced this issue? The expected behavior is not restart the whole application and hot swap only the changed artifacts.

Edit:

Here's the UserController sample:

```
@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class UserController{

    @Autowired
    private IUserService userService;
    ...
}
```

Comment: is your `UserService` annotated with `@Service`? Could you please extend your question with Class signatures including their annotations?

Comment: Can you start your application at all? Or you are having issues with hot swap feature?

Comment: @HakanDilek yes, it is as pointed at the 7th note about the environment. Also, the application starts just fine and processes requests as well. The issue happens when I try to change something when debugging an already executing application.

Comment: Perhaps, you are missing out on any of the annotations, might be `@Controller` or `@RestController` on `UserController` or `@Service` on `UserService`

Comment: Updated the post description. The controller seems properly set.

Comment: Does `UserService` actually implement `IUserService`? e.g. `public class UserService implements IUserService { ...`?

Comment: Yes, `UserService` does implement `IUserService`.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in the Spring Boot run configuration to try hot swapping before restarting the application context:

[image]

The correct trigger file option will automatically be added to the command line.