# How to resolve Error:java: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

this is my pom and i have still the same error Error:java: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

my java version is 9.0.4.
actually I saw this link but I have still the error
 [How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j/57903165#57903165)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.banking</groupId>
  <artifactId>payment</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.7-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>payment</name>
  <description>Payment management system</description>

  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <mapstruct.version>1.2.0.Final</mapstruct.version>
    <projectlombok.version>1.18.4</projectlombok.version>
    <bouncycastle.version>1.56</bouncycastle.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.3.7.Final</hibernate.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
      <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-test -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mashape.unirest/unirest-java -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
      <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.allanditzel/spring-security-csrf-token-filter -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.allanditzel</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-csrf-token-filter</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
      <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
      <version>0.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.nimbusds/oauth2-oidc-sdk -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
      <artifactId>oauth2-oidc-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>4.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.validator/hibernate-validator -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot-starter -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
      <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-jaxrs -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>4.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.ws/jaxws-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-rt -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.10</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.ws/rt -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.stream.buffer/streambuffer -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.stream.buffer</groupId>
      <artifactId>streambuffer</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.ws/policy -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>policy</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.jws/jsr181-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsr181-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-MR1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.soap/javax.xml.soap-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.xml.soap-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj/saaj-impl -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
      <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.gmbal/gmbal-api-only -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.gmbal</groupId>
      <artifactId>gmbal-api-only</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0-b023</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
      <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
      <version>${bouncycastle.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/rg.bouncycastle/bcmail-jdk15on -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
      <artifactId>bcmail-jdk15on</artifactId>
      <version>${bouncycastle.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>${projectlombok.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-actuator -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mapstruct/mapstruct-jdk8 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
      <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
      <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
              <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
              <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
            </path>
            <!-- For JPA static metamodel generation -->
            <path>
              <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
              <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
              <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            </path>

          </annotationProcessorPaths>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding  <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>?

Comment: I have added javax.activation but I have still the error

Comment: I think it may be a problem of the compiler that reads the classes from an unwanted package. I've solved such a problem recently. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57866555/log4j2-in-spring-boot-is-not-using-the-pattern-in-the-xml-file (including comments and attempts) and see if it helps. It was a gradle project, but the logic is the same.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same situation.
Try this dependency. I think it will be greate.
This dependency good for java 9+ version.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
  <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
  <version>3.25.0-GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Adding a completley unrelated dependency is probably not the proper solution here