# Spring Boot + Jetty & hot deployment

Tags: spring, maven, deployment, jetty, spring-boot

I've read the [Hot swapping in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399586/spring-boot-developer-machine) but didn't find something that will help my case.

I have a spring-boot app on embedded jetty servers using thymeleaf. My app will serve html,css,js(AngularJS) and REST services.

Folder structure is like this:

```
/java
   ----
/resources
   /static
       /js
       /css
   /templates (html)
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But css/html/js is not hot deployed when I change them. I have to restart server every time. 
+bonus = when page loads it locks resources (js) and even Ant script cannot replace them.

Can I set scanIntervalSeconds anywhere?

--EDIT--

Main.java

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Import({RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class, PersistenceConfig.class, ThymeleafConfig.class})
public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
   }
}
```

I've run it by right click on class and Debug in IDEA.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How are you launching the app? If you use an IDE with debug mode it should work (except for the locking problem which I believe is Windows OS), or if you launch it with "mvn spring-boot:run", or "gradle bootRun".

Comment: Thank you :-) "mvn spring-boot:run" is working, how do I run it in debug mode from terminal?

Comment: How about `MAVEN_OPTS= -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000`?

Comment: I've put it in Maven->Importing->VM options for importer but no luck. I should still run it with "mvn spring-boot:run"? Change server to localhost?

Comment: Sorry I didn't follow that. What's "importer"? If you are running on the command line, just set an environment variable (as suggested, with `server=y`). Google "java remote debug" if you want to find out more about how to do that.

Comment: Faced the same problem with embedded Tomcat and FreeMarker, and Dave's solution worked: `mvn spring-boot:run`

Answer (score 2):

I develop  using NetBeans 8.0.1.
I fixed the issue of not reloaded static resources in src/main/resources like css (in src/main/resources/resources/css (yes, really twice "resources"!), html-thymeleaf-templates (in src/main/resources/templates) the following way:

- My Spring Boot webapp is a JAR project (pom.xml)
- Add src/main/resources/application.properties:

  - spring.template.cache=false
  - spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
- Added custom maven build: Project - Properties - Custom... - Goals...
- Execute Goals: spring-boot:run
- Set Properties:

  - jpda.listen=maven (to run it in debug mode)
  - Env.spring.profiles.active=DEV (optional, but I need it for different SpringConfig-....properties in development, production,...)

Just run the custom maven build for starting the webapp in debug mode. Changes in Thymeleaf-Templates (that are in src/main/resources/templates, eg. index.html (not .xhtml!)) are visible immediately on browser reload.

Answer (score 1):

if you move the css and java script to a folder under 
src/main/java/webapp it should work.

for some reason resources under src/main/java/resources didnt seem to get hot deployed when changed.

to fix this as the above post suggested I added

- spring.template.cache=false
- spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
  to Application.properties inside the resources folder.

Note: 
I also added this

- -javaagent:springloaded-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar -noverify

as a vm runtime argument.