# Thymeleaf Not Hot Swapping Intellij

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, thymeleaf, jvm-hotspot

I am having some issues getting my Thymeleaf templates to hot swap / update using Intellij. At the moment I have to do a full server restart in order to see my changes, which is rather tedious and slows down my work flow.

I am using Gradle, Intellij 14.1, and Tomcat 8. I am running the application in Debug mode.

I have tried setting Thymeleaf to not cacheable.

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig {

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix(environment.getRequiredProperty("thymeleaf.resolver.prefix"));
        resolver.setSuffix(environment.getRequiredProperty("thymeleaf.resolver.suffix"));
        resolver.setTemplateMode(environment.getRequiredProperty("thymeleaf.resolver.templatemode"));
        resolver.setOrder(environment.getRequiredProperty("thymeleaf.resolver.order", Integer.class));
        resolver.setCacheable(environment.getRequiredProperty("thymeleaf.resolver.cacheable", Boolean.class));
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding(environment.getRequiredProperty("thymeleaf.resolver.character.encoding"));
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        engine.addDialect(new LayoutDialect());
        engine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());
        return engine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

Property file the above code is reading from.

```
# Thymeleaf
thymeleaf.resolver.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
thymeleaf.resolver.suffix=.html
thymeleaf.resolver.templatemode=HTML5
thymeleaf.resolver.order=1
thymeleaf.resolver.cacheable=false
thymeleaf.resolver.character.encoding=UTF-8
```

I also tried setting it in the ApplicationInitializer.

```
 @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

        /**
         * If no active profile is set via -Dspring.profiles.active then the application
         * will default to development mode
         */
        container.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.default", "dev");

        /**
         * Set thymeleaf cache to false if -Dspring.thymeleaf.cache is not passed
         */
        container.setInitParameter("spring.thymeleaf.cache", "false");

        /**
         * create the root Spring application context
         */
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.setDisplayName("app");
        rootContext.register(AppConfig.class);

        /**
         * manage the lifecycle of the root application context
         */
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        /**
         * register and map the dispatcher servlet
         */
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

So far none of this has worked.

Comment: Thymeleaf templates & static resources can be reloaded without building, if you source them from the filesystem rather than the classpath:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/72928208/768795

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select exploded war for the deployment. Then you can simply update resources or classes and resources when you hit CMD + F10( I assume it might be CTRL on Windows/Linux).

Comment: Did you get it to work on Windows? Funny thing but it doesn't work for me now o Windows (it does on Mac).

Comment: also this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399586/hot-swapping-in-spring-boot/43114954#43114954