# How to implement hot swapping (not automatic restart) in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

Hot reloading can be achieved by using spring dev tools

example https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-application-live-reload-hot-swap-with

but is there any way to do achieve true hot swap in spring boot. i know we can do automatic restart with **spring boot dev tools** . but i do not want to restart(i.e **automatically/manually**) the server every changes i make. i just need to update the **byte code of java class** i made change..

Comment: Check out this post, I feel it has touched all of these questions that you may ask.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399586/hot-swapping-in-spring-boot

Answer (score 2):

> Hot reloading can be achieved by using spring dev tools

To an extent yes. As stated in the docs (emphasis mine)

> Since Spring Boot applications are just plain Java applications, JVM hot-swapping ***should*** work out of the box. **JVM hot swapping is somewhat limited with the bytecode that it can replace**. For a more complete solution, *JRebel* can be used.

Ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-hot-swapping

So you'll want to configure [JRebel with Spring Boot](https://manuals.jrebel.com/jrebel/standalone/springboot.html) for more advanced hot swapping. There are a plethora of tutorials out there.

Comment: Thanks!!! JRebel is good, but its costly, is there any JRebel alternate with free or less cost ???

Comment: @thaveethugce HotswapAgent and DCEVM is free